# Increased database size after a mongodb repair

Tags: mongodb, repair, database

I have used `mongodb --repair` in the past to recover sparse space due to document deletion; but never in my time have I experienced an increase in DB size using the `--repair` process.

I have ran the repair three times on the original data, and every time DB size is increased.

I started with a `558 GB` database.

**Original**

```
> db.stats()
{
    "db" : "selfservice",
    "collections" : 4,
    "objects" : 2821806,
    "avgObjSize" : 190351.89918229674,
    "dataSize" : 537136131224,
    "storageSize" : 558518763536,
    "numExtents" : 291,
    "indexes" : 12,
    "indexSize" : 1314422816,
    "fileSize" : 566592798720,
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,
    "dataFileVersion" : {
        "major" : 4,
        "minor" : 5
    },
    "extentFreeList" : {
        "num" : 17,
        "totalSize" : 5067198464
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

...and ended up with a `786 GB` database.

**Repaired**

```
> db.stats()
{
    "db" : "selfservice",
    "collections" : 4,
    "objects" : 2821806,
    "avgObjSize" : 277948.7895397487,
    "dataSize" : 784317562016,
    "storageSize" : 786090391904,
    "numExtents" : 399,
    "indexes" : 12,
    "indexSize" : 1082731328,
    "fileSize" : 789822046208,
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,
    "dataFileVersion" : {
        "major" : 4,
        "minor" : 5
    },
    "extentFreeList" : {
        "num" : 0,
        "totalSize" : 0
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

My document count has not changed

**Original**

```
> db.docs.find().count()
2784992
```

**Repaired**

```
> db.docs.find().count()
2784992
```

I do have documents deleted out of the original DB and space to reclaim, but why DB size is increasing after a `--repair` I'm clueless.
The repair log has no indication why; no errors, no problems ...just a whole lot more 2GB files allocated then original DB.

Anyone got any ideas?

Mongodb: 2.6.7

Comment: Is this perhaps the first time you've done a repair on MongoDB 2.6 after upgrading from an older version of MongoDB? The default allocation strategy in MongoDB 2.6 changed to [`powerOf2Sizes`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6/#storage) which uses more space initially but generally results in better storage re-use over time. If you are using GridFS and have chunks created in an older driver version, this can also lead to excessive storage usage if you rebuild with powerOf2Sizes ( [SERVER-13331](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13331)).

Comment: The allocation strategy can be set per collection (using [`collMod`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/collMod/)) and as a server default. If not explicitly set for a collection, a repair or resync will use the default allocation strategy.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I was encountering!
I have updated my mongodb command to use old method `mongo --repair --setParameter newCollectionsUsePowerOf2Sizes=false ...` Due to how we use MongoDB we don't update existing documents so old behavior is more appropriate for us. Thanks!